# Deploying single Codebuild project to multiple ECS containers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I use codebuild & codepipeline successfully for continuous deployment onto ECS for several projects but have came up with a problem.
In this project I need to deploy the same build to **four different ECS containers**.

The default way I use codebuild and codepipeline CD is as shown in aws docs - I create imagedefinitions.json file at the end of the build process. 
As far as I can see this file can contain the definition of **only one ECS container**.

You have to provide the name of the container:

```
post_build:
commands:
  - echo Build completed on `date`
  - echo Pushing the Docker images...
  - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest
  - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
  - echo Writing image definitions file...
  - printf '[{"name":"hello-world","imageUri":"%s"}]' $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG > imagedefinitions.json
artifacts:
files: imagedefinitions.json
```

For this task defintion:

```
{
"taskDefinition": {
"family": "hello-world",
"containerDefinitions": [
  {
    "name": "hello-world",
    "image": "012345678910.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/hello-world:6a57b99",
    "cpu": 100,
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "protocol": "tcp",
        "containerPort": 80,
        "hostPort": 80
      }
    ],
    "memory": 128,
    "essential": true
  }
]
```

It *could* work if I change the names of all four containers in the different services to the same name. for example that specific image name. But I can't tell if this is a good idea.

Now I wonder if I can use codepipeline to ECS in this project at all or should I deploy in a different way.

Comment: why dont you use single ECR repository / single image for the services?

Comment: I do use a single ECR image. I'm migrating our CD into aws, so the system is already running, and currently each service that uses that same image has a different name for the container. I'm not sure why shouldn't I just change the name for the container to that image name.

Comment: actually it doesn't matter if you have same container name under different services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeBuild action in codePipeline currently supports only one output artifact. You can zip all the image definition files in to one zip file and add a lambda invoke action to split it in to multiple artifacts and use them in ECS deploy actions.

Answer (score 2):

You can construct the file to list multiple container-image pairs in the **imagedefinitions.json** file like below:

```
[{
  "name": "simple-app",
  "imageUri": "httpd:2.4"
},
{
  "name": "simple-app",
  "imageUri": "mysql"
},
{
  "name": "simple-app-2",
  "imageUri": "java1.8"
}]
```

Here is an example of how it is done in my buildspec.yml file:

```
 post_build:
   commands:
     - docker push $IMAGE1_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
     - docker push $IMAGE2_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
     - printf '[{"name":"conatiner1_name","imageUri":"%s"}, {"name":"container2_name","imageUri":"%s"}]' $IMAGE1_URI:$IMAGE_TAG $IMAGE2_URI:$IMAGE_TAG > imagedefinitions.json
```

More details here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/file-reference.html#pipelines-create-image-definitions

Comment: Requires the containers are in the same task.

Comment: Agree with @mtrolle - if your deployment uses more than one service which spins up another container - the ECS deploy complains that simple-app for instance doesn't exist in the simple-app-2 service...

Answer (score 1):

We are running CodeBuild as an action under CodePipeline.

Here's an example for running two different ECS service tasks on the same ECR image:

```
phases:
  install: ...
  pre_build: ...
  build: ...
  post_build:
    commands:
    - ...
    - printf '[{"name":"web","imageUri":"%s"}]' $ECR_REPOSITORY_URL:$LATEST_VERSION > web_image_definitions.json
    - printf '[{"name":"worker","imageUri":"%s"}]' $ECR_REPOSITORY_URL:$LATEST_VERSION > worker_image_definitions.json
artifacts:
  files:
    - web_image_definitions.json
    - worker_image_definitions.json
```

Now in your CodePipeline action for the build action you wanna set `Output artifacts` to be named e.g. `BuildOutput`.

Next create two Deploy actions (one for each ECS service) and for the respective deployment actions you wanna ensure to set `Input artifacts` to `BuildOutput` and set `Image definitions file - optional` to respectively `web_image_definitions.json` and `worker_image_definitions.json` for each deploy action.
[image: AWS console screendump showing input field for image definitions in CodePipeline action editor]